# How can I divide and print the beginning of fields for each unique ID?

Tags: awk

I need to divide the the first record of `$6` by first record of `$4` for each unique ID($1).

```
4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5    3 11.5  
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03  543.667 3  11.5  
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539   3    11.5  
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535  3     11.5  
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488  3     17.5  
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5 3    17.5   
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5 3    17.5  
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472  3     17.5
```

the output will look like this,

```
4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5    3 11.5  0.02  
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03  543.667 3  11.5  0.02   
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539   3    11.5  0.02  
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535  3     11.5  0.02  
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488  3     17.5  0.036  
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5 3    17.5  0.036   
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5 3    17.5  0.036  
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472  3     17.5  0.036
```

Comment: Does the 0.02 come from 11.5/546.5? And the 0.036 from 17.5/488.3?

Comment: What do you mean by "for each unique ID($1)." In your example output  `$1` is not unique. There are many lines starting with `4` and `10` in `$1`. Dou want to remove the last three lines that begin with `4` and also remove the last three lines that begin with `10`?

Comment: To get the example output from the question, a `awk '{printf("%s%s%5.3f\n", $0, FS, $6/$4) }' yourfile` is sufficient.

Comment: You've posted enough questions and got enough answers over the past few weeks that you should be able to start attempting to solve some of your problems on your own. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far and ask specific questions about where you're getting stuck rather than once again showing no attempt and just asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$6/$4} {printf "%s\t%.3f\n",$0,a[$1]}' file

4   2016-07-19  06:09:50  546.5    3 11.5       0.021
4   2016-07-20  06:40:03  543.667 3  11.5       0.021
4   2016-07-21  05:43:18  539   3    11.5       0.021
4   2016-07-22  07:18:20  535  3     11.5       0.021
10  2016-07-20  08:08:45  488  3     17.5       0.036
10  2016-07-21  07:32:35  490.5 3    17.5       0.036
10  2016-07-23  06:01:58  470.5 3    17.5       0.036
10  2016-07-24  08:26:02  472  3     17.5       0.036
```

your output format is not consistent (2 or 3 decimal digits), there are ways to match exactly but not sure it was intentional.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'p!=$1{q=sprintf("%.3f", $6/$4)} {$(NF+1)=q;p=$1}1' file
4 2016-07-19 06:09:50 546.5 3 11.5 0.021
4 2016-07-20 06:40:03 543.667 3 11.5 0.021
4 2016-07-21 05:43:18 539 3 11.5 0.021
4 2016-07-22 07:18:20 535 3 11.5 0.021
10 2016-07-20 08:08:45 488 3 17.5 0.036
10 2016-07-21 07:32:35 490.5 3 17.5 0.036
10 2016-07-23 06:01:58 470.5 3 17.5 0.036
10 2016-07-24 08:26:02 472 3 17.5 0.036
```

Explained:

```
p!=$1 {                       # when the $1 changes
    q=sprintf("%.3f", $6/$4)  # calculate the value q to append to records
} 
{                             # for all records
    $(NF+1)=q                 # append q to them
    p=$1                      # remember previous $1
} 1                           # print
```

Comment: It just divide the field of $6 by $4 for each line. but i need to divide the beginning of these field so that all the lines of unique ID will have same result. Could you check for that. thanks

Comment: It only makes the division for each new `$1`. The previous version didn't.

Comment: My interest is to divide only the very first record of the two field  for each ID and print. the data is sorted.

Comment: I Just checked it and it just divide for each line.

Answer (score 1):

@Alula- same logic as karakfa, but in spite of going through the loop first and then printing, doing that check within print itself.

```
awk '{printf "%s\t%.3f\n",$0,!a[$1]?a[$1]=$6/$4:a[$1]}'  Input_file
```

I hope this helps you.